# Form API Подсчет суммы в полях и вывод 3 поле

Tags: php, drupal

Ребят такая проблема, имеется  два поля в которых вводятся данные и в третьем поле без перезагруки страницы нужно вывести результат формулы к примеру 1 поле + 2 поле.

```
$form['str3']['t1c'] = array(
    '#title' => '',
    '#description' => '',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength' => 150,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $data['t1c'],
    '#size' => 10,
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => '1C'),
  );

  $form['str3']['t2c'] = array(
    '#title' => '',
    '#description' => '',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength' => 150,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $data['t2c'],
    '#size' => 10,
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => '2C'),
  );

  $form['str3']['t3c'] = array(
    '#title' => '',
    '#description' => '',
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#maxlength' => 150,
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#default_value' => $data['t3c'],
    '#size' => 10,
    '#attributes' => array('placeholder' => '3C'),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно создать javascript-файл, где при изменении 1го или 2го поля вы проверяете заполнено ли другое поле (чтобы реагировать только, когда заполнены оба поля) и обновляете значение 3го поля.
   См. https://www.drupal.org/node/287217
2. Крепите этот файл к вашей форме

   ```
   $form['#attached']['js'] = array(
     drupal_get_path('module', 'example') . '/example.js',
   );
   ```

Comment: Просто я думал можно стандартными методами drupal api и написанием функци в самом модуле, чем подключение стороннего скрипта.

Comment: @МихаилБегунков, вы, наверное, можете использовать Drupal AJAX API, только это избыточно. Похоже, что решение на JS проще всего.

Comment: Согласен с @DmitriySimushev. Каждый AJAX-запрос будет заставлять PHP загружать полностью весь друпал (в 8ке этого уже не будет, а в 7ке чтобы этого избежать нужно ещё постараться). А загрузить сервер для подсчёта суммы двух полей просто нерационально. Проще и быстрее сделать это с помощью javascript.